# Save and Restore state of a TableView (which columns are hidden, width of columns) in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, tableview, customization

### Intro

In a TableView I have 4 columns: id, name, price, quantity. Now I have 3 users that might want to customize the TableView to their likings. E.g. user1 wants only 3 columns to be displayed with the last column to be hidden away, while user 2 wants a different column width for the name column.

### Issue

How can I preserve the state of the TableView including the state of all its columns into a preference file and load them at the start of the application, so that the customized view will be restored for each user?

Comment: There's no built-in mechanism to do this. You simply have to save the information into a file, in the format of your choosing, when the application closes and reload it again when the application starts.

Comment: Thanks for your input, James! But I don't know where to start (what information are needed to restore the width and visibility properties of columns) Could you provide me with a code to jump start ? So that I can have at least an orientation of what needs to be done.

Comment: Which particular part are you stuck on? This question as it stands is far too broad.

Comment: *"what information are needed to restore the width and visibility properties of columns"* The widths and visibility of the columns when the application close?

Comment: Yeah you are right! My question was not clear enough. Austin just gave me a very useful insight. I think I can work with the info he provided. Thanks again for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you are going to need to do is choose your storage method I recommend either json or xml both have their benefits and have extensive support. Next your going to figure out what values you are going to be storing

1. All of the columns
2. All the columns widths
3. If the column is visible

Now here is an example of how you could store these values

**JSON**

---

```
{
    name : {
        width:100,
        showing:false
    },
    id : {
        width:50,
        showing:false
    },
    etc.
}
```

**XML**

---

```
<properties>
    <name>
        <width>100</width>
        <showing>false</showing>
    </name>
    <id>
        <width>50</width>
        <showing>true</showing>
    </id>
    etc.
</properties>
```

Next when and how to get column values if you want them to constantly be upto date (not recommended) it reports every number say going from 1 to 50 it will report 1,2,3...50. You would have to figure out a way to filter out those unneeded values.

```
       public void changelistener(final TableColumn listerColumn) {
        listerColumn.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number t, Number t1) {
                propertyStore.storeWidth(listerColumn.getText(),t1);//when the values are stored
            }
        });
    }
```

attach by doing `changelistener(YourColumn);`

The better option would be to save  the values whenever the program is closed

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        public void handle(WindowEvent we) {
           for(int i = 0; i<tv.getColumns().size();i++)
           {
               TableColumn x = (TableColumn) tv.getColumns().get(i);
               propertyStore.storeWidth(x.getText(),x.getWidth());
               propertyStore.storeVisible(x.getText(),x.isVisible());
               //other option 
               propertyStore.storeWidth(x.getId(),x.getWidth());
               propertyStore.storeVisible(x.getId(),x.isVisible());
           }
        }
    });
```

If you use the getId() you will need to set an Id for each of the columns like so

```
TableColumn example = new TableColumn("example");
example.setId("ExampleID");
System.out.println(example.getId());//will print ExampleId
```

**Storing your values**

Finally you will need to create a class to store and get your values from your storage file

Comment: `stage.setOnCloseRequest` does not define a handler that gets invoked when the application closes. The handler is invoked when there is an *external* request to close the *stage*. So if you have multiple windows this might get called too frequently, and if you close the last open window with code (e.g. in an event handler) it won't get called at all. Override `Application.stop()` to have code that is executed when the application exits.

Comment: YES! This is awesome, Austin! I certainly can work with your provided information. So I was thinking to create a new TableProperties.class for each user to store/restore the visibility and the width for each TableColumn. But the only way to identify/address a certain TableColumn is by its header text?

Comment: @James_D Thanks for the clarification. I think I will go with Austin's proposed stage.setOnCloseRequest() since it will totally suffice my environment. But I do see certain scenarios in which the storing should occur within Application.stop().

Comment: @Chiggiddi If you only have one window, at least use `setOnHidden(...)`, which is guaranteed to be invoked when the window closes.

Comment: @James_D I still have problems to differentiate between `stage.close()` and `stage.hide()` but they should be the same; while `stage.setOnHidden(...)` and `stage.setOnCloseRequest(...)` are of different nature. So the **external request** is here the differentiator? Does this mean that `stage.setOnCloseRequest(...)` only will be called when the user explicitly presses the close Button? In contrast when stage.close() or stage.hide() is called internally  `stage.setOnCloseRequest(...)` wouldn't run?

Comment: `stage.close()` and `stage.hide()` are [synonymous](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#close--). An external request is essentially one made by the operating system: since the standard window buttons are created by the native windowing toolkit, that includes the standard window close button. So `setOnCloseRequest` handlers are only invoked from "native" calls, such as the standard window close button and things like CMD-Q on a Mac.

Comment: @Chiggiddi Besides the name you could set the id of the columns then use that as their Identifier but that might mess with css if you are using it. I have added the example

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that you could just hard code every Column saving, however that makes for a longer program, that is harder to change and add on to. So I would recommend against this

Comment: @Austin I see you point. Yes hardcoding is not really appropriate here. I will post my solution once I have finished coding and testing. Thanks again for your assistance!

Comment: @James_D thank you so much for your clarification. Now all is very clear in my mind.